# Ms EXCEL: Copy contents of Clicked/Active Cell to another Cell

Tags: excel, click, cell

This seems rather an easy task, but somehow nothing has worked since I have tried several solutions to now...

I want something, supposing we have this sheet:

[image]

When a Cell is Clicked **randomly**, the value/contents of that text should be shown in the Orange Box.

> **That's the first and most important part.**

**The second thing to happen is:**
if possible, all other Cells that contain the same value should be highlighted/shaded with an Green Background (See image)

[image]

I have tried:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/10/excel-indirect-function/

http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-display-cell-values-c94b3493-7762-4a53-8461-fb5cd9f05c33

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf

Thank you in advance.

> **EDIT 1:** PS: Preferably a Non-VB solution. However, if a VB solution would be all there is, then your VB suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: VBA could do it. Why do you wish to have a non-VBA solution?

Comment: Sure, see EDIT 1:...  Thank you!

Comment: Do you want this to happen **even if you click on an empty cell** ??

Comment: Just thinking of it, If it causes a challenge to exclude the Empty Cells, a solution that affects even the Clicked-Empty-Cells is welcome.....  Thank You...

Comment: You may get an answer but in general Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  I see you have done your research on trying to find a non vba method, as far as I know this is not possible with formulas and other non vba methods.  Have you tried any vba methods?

Comment: Sure... I was going this way with the VB: `Sub SetValue()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveCell.Value 'To show in the orange box'
End Sub` ... Not so much into VB/Excel programming though..

Comment: You need to look at the worksheet-selection_change event for the Wroksheet object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/663580/trigger-macro-with-one-click-on-specific-cell) so it just needs editing a bit

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
     'Put in your actual range and the cell where you the text to be shown
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:D17")) Is Nothing Then
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("E2")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and the colouring can just be done with a conditional formatting rule

```
=B5=$E$2
```

assuming that the values start in B5 and the text to be displayed is in E2.

If you only want to copy the value and not the formatting to E2, replace

```
Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("E2")
```

with

```
Range("E2").Value = Selection.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Task1: Show your active cell contents in cell E2
    actval = ActiveCell.Value
    actaddr = ActiveCell.Address
    Range("E2") = actval

    'Task2: Turn all cells green, matching with active cell value, except host cell

    'first set entire background white
    Range("B5:F18").Interior.Color = vbWhite

    'second set all matching cells green
    For Each c In Range("B5:F18")
    If c.Address <> actaddr Then
    If c = actval Then
    Range(c.Address).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
    End If
    Next c
    End Sub
```